# FileSystemWatcher - Which process caused the update

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

To investigate a problem that we have with SharePoint 2007, I wrote a small application that monitors a folder for security changes and logs the exact date and time from these changes. I use the FileSystemWatcher to do this.

We do this because from time to time, some process alters the security settings from all folders below c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\virtualdirectories, causing access denied exceptions on Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll.

Now I was wondering if there is a way to check which process is responsible for the security updates. That would most likely help us a lot in troubleshooting this weird problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write it yourself but use a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)?

Comment: Nice tool. I'm a developer, not a system admin, so I'm not familiar with all the tools available. I'll mark your answer as accepted because it helps me find the cause. But as a developer I  would still like to know if it's possible to do this in C# and how. One can never know too much, right !?